# Wordpress admin menu. Pages not showing icons or Portfolio slideshow plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have been sent a Wordpress installation that has been recovered from s client who is asking me to reinstall it and sort any issues with it, before hostin git on our server. 
I have got it to a point where it is 99% ready but I am having an issue in regards to the admin menu and a plugin that I can't seem to solve.

I have installed a plugin called Portfolio slideshow (which was present before he sent it to me) which should show on the edit page screen underneath the content box as shown below:

I will try and explain it with two pictures below:

This is the old site which is working correctly. As you can see, the pages in the admin bar are correct and have an icon next to them. The plugin panel is showing correctly at the bottom. I have highlighted these:

[image]

And this is the site currently. As you can see, the icons are missing next to the pages and the plugin panel is missing from the edit page screen.

[image]

I have tried re-installing the plugin (portfolio slideshow), looked in the settings, adding new pages, re-uploading the wp-includes and wp-admin files, et, and nothing.
Does anybody know why this may be occurring? Also, how do you actually get pages to sit in the main admin menu like in the screenshot rather than under the 'pages' section? This may help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to open wp-config.php and add this:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);

define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

Then check the .htaccess file, it should have:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

That helped me to solve the same problem with you.